# how to create an array like "Map.Entry<Integer，Integer>"?

Tags: java

codes in java like this "`Integer[] integers=new Integer[10];`" are fine,when I try codes like `"Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>[] entrys=new Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>[number];"`,I get the following error :

### Cannot create a generic array of Map.Entry

then I create a class:

```
class createTarray<T>{
T[] ts;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public  createTarray(Class<?> class1,int length) {
ts=(T[])Array.newInstance(class1, length);
}
public T[] getTarray() {
return ts;
}
}
```

---

and try to get array with codes bellow:

```
createTarray<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> tarray=new createTarray<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>.class,number);

entrys=tarray.getTarray();
```

---

and also get error:

```
Multiple markers at this line


- Integer cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Integer cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token ">", void expected after 
     this token
```

---

so could someone help me out? I get quite confused these days by this

Comment: You can't really create a generic array. The biggest question is why are you even trying?

Comment: If you have a bunch of `Map.Entry` objects, is there any reason not  to put them in a `Map`?

Comment: Yeah, is this code supposed to do something useful, or are you just playing around?

Comment: In that case you case `List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` incase you want index based fast access you can create `Map` and store indexes in key and `Entry<>` as values.